# ascending order of data from database by Id

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am trying to learn asp.net-core, and I am stuck on trying to retieve the data from database in ascending order of database Id, my code is below but not sure why its not doing it, it does acccessnding order by page but I want all the data in ascending order by database Id, any pointers wold be great...

```
    @model IEnumerable<Citrus.Models.Customers>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";

    Pager pager = new Pager();
    int pageNo = 0;

    if (ViewBag.Pager !=null)

    {
        pager = ViewBag.Pager;
        pageNo = pager.CurrentPage;
    }


}


<form asp-controller="Customers" asp-action="Index">
    <p>


        <div class="container body-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="searchString"></label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchString" placeholder="Search by company name" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn" name="searchString"><button class="btn btn-default btn-primary mr-1"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search</button></span>
                            @*<span asp-validation-for="searchString"></span>*@
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Create"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i> Customer</></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </p>

</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tel)
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                                
        @foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tel)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="container">
    @if (pager.TotalPages > 0)

    {
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">

@if (pager.CurrentPage > 1)
{ 

    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" asp-controller="Customers" asp-action="Index" asp-route-pg="1">First</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-link" asp-controller="Customers" asp-action="Index" asp-route-pg="@(pager.CurrentPage -1)">Previous</a>

        </li>
}
















        @for (var pge = pager.StartPage; pge <= pager.EndPage; pge++)

        {
            <li class="page-item @(pge == pager.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                <a class="page-link" asp-controller="Customers" asp-action="Index" asp-route-pg="@pge"> @pge</a>
            </li> 
        }


            @if (pager.CurrentPage < pager.TotalPages)

            {
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" asp-controller="Customers" asp-action="Index" asp-route-pg="@(pager.CurrentPage + 1)">Next</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-link" asp-controller="Customers" asp-action="Index" asp-route-pg="@(pager.TotalPages)">Last</a>
                </li>

            }

        </ul>

    }




</div>
```

Many Thank
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `OrderBy` in backend,use `OrderBy` firstly,and then get the current page data,for example:

```
List<Citrus.Models.Customers> data = _context.Customers
    .OrderBy(c => c.Id)
    .Skip(position).Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

For details,you can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/pagination).

Comment: Hi Yiyi, apologies for my lack of knowledge... is this done at the controller level or within the data folder where the context file is located? 
Many Thanks 

John

Comment: In your corresponding action for the view.